# Create S3 Bucket and upload code in Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-s3, serverless, serverless-framework

**serverless.yml**

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  deploymentBucket:
    name: myS3Bucket
  resources:
    Resources:
      MyLambdaBucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          BucketName: ${self.provider.deploymentBucket.name}
```

I would like to specify bucket name, at the same time if bucket doesn't exist I'd like to create bucket first.

But I got an Error

> Error:
> Could not locate deployment bucket: "myS3Bucket". Error: The specified bucket does not exist

How can I create bucket if it doesn't exist, and deploy to the bucket?

Comment: Can you try adding `existing: true` in your serverless.yml?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your syntax. Try this:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  custom:
    deploymentBucket: 'myS3Bucket'
  resources:
    Resources:
      MyLambdaBucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          BucketName: ${self.provider.custom.deploymentBucket}
```

Note the difference with quotes, I'm also not using name here and I also use a `custom` key to have all the custom variables together.